# Close Responsive/mobile Navigation when link is clicked

Tags: jquery, mobile, navigation, hide

I've researched on here to find a solution but none seem to solve my problem.

my website: https://ayliffe.000webhostapp.com/

When the window is resized to it's smallest and the menu icon is clicked, it reveals the mobile navigation. I'd like it so when a link is clicked, the navigation then hides(without the user having to click the menu icon again)

I know it's probably an onclick event with jQuery, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.
Put jquery `.toggle` in your `myfunction`

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#mainNav").toggle();
    var x = document.getElementById("mainNav");
    if (x.className === "nav-wrap") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "nav-wrap";
    }
}
```

And write this click event for your menu list.

```
$("#mainNav ul li").click(function(e) {
  $("#mainNav").toggle()
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I pasted '<script>
$("#mainNav").toggle();
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mainNav");
    if (x.className === "nav-wrap") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "nav-wrap";
    }
}
</script>
<script>
$("#mainNav ul li").click(function(e) {
$("#mainNav").toggle()
})
</script>'

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gsdwvr4d/ 
Try by placing the toggle inside myfunction

Comment: Still wouldn't work. Here's a codepen if it helps http://codepen.io/ayliffe1987/pen/YGvJdp

Comment: Please check your console it is saying $ is undefind.
Please resolve that first

Comment: Ok the codepen has been updated. Took away all javascript except the bit for my nav

Comment: I think your not including the Jquery library in your project.
Please add following library in your project 
https://code.jquery.com/